# What is the difference between binary data of an image and the translated data that the GPU sends to the monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, images, graphics

I'm reading about GPU's, and they say that a CPU generally cannot perform the complex calcuations required to translate an image's binary data to create the actual image, but what does this mean exactly?  What type of data format is sent to the monitor?  In other words, how does the GPU tell the monitor what to display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a computer render an object to the screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/194802/how-does-a-computer-render-an-object-to-the-screen)

Comment: Actually the CPU could do it, its just that the GPU can do it faster, several dozen times faster.  The real problem is that because the GPU exists, the binary data created by a GPU, is now required to process said binary data ( because of the size of the binary data ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between binary data of an image and the translated data that the GPU sends to the monitor?

For all intents and purposes, *nothing*; data is data. An image’s binary data depends on its format, but ultimately, all images end up as a bitmap which indicates the color of each pixel in each row and column of the image. The video-adapter then sends that data to the monitor which turns those pixels on or off at those colors and intensities, and we see the result as an image.

> I'm reading about GPU's, and they say that a CPU generally cannot perform the complex calcuations required to translate an image's binary data to create the actual image, but what does this mean exactly?

In that context, it is almost certainly talking about advanced video rendering such as 3D-graphics or special-effects processing.

In the past, the CPU was responsible for most of the rendering done in games and video-editing programs, but the increase in demand for graphical complexity has made it impossible for CPUs (which are general-purposes processors) to perform the advanced mathematical calculations required for advanced graphics related operations, especially if it already has to do a lot of other processing like handling physics, AI, etc. in games.

In response, GPUs got more advanced and started including more complex, and specialized circuitry to allow them to do the processing themselves. Now, instead of having the CPU process something like the source of a [ray-traced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray-tracing) image or a [shader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader_%28realtime,_logical%29), it can be sent directly to the GPU to process it. Then the video-adapter can either return the result to the CPU for further processing or simply output it to the screen.

> What type of data format is sent to the monitor? In other words, how does the GPU tell the monitor what to display?

This isn’t really the place for complex specifications (you can ask that at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)), but the monitor only receives information about which pixels to light up; it doesn’t actually get *data* like files or bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The image is compressed. The data going to the monitor is resized, antialiased/subpixelrendered and copied into the desktop image.